# Two column div and width percentage

Tags: html, css

I have problem using `width:100%`, it does not stretch to entire screen width but if I specify it using pixels, it will work. I don't understand how it works. I want to use percentage to adjust automatically on any screen sizes.

```
/*width: 600px; */    /* THIS WILL WORK */
width: 100%;           /*WON'T WORK*/
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utBRH/9/

CSS:

```
    #wrapper{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        position:relative;
    }

    #search_box {   
        background-color:#050505;
        height:300px;
        /*width: 600px; */    /* THIS WILL WORK */
        width: 100%;           /*WON'T WORK*/ 
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;

    }

    #btn_search_orange{
     display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      height: 80%;
      text-align: left;
      background-color:#e47700;
    }

    #btn_search_black{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      height: 80%;
      text-align: left;
      background-color:#555454;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inorder to make that work, you need to assign `display: table;` and `width: 100%;` to the parent element because child element is set to `display: table-cell;`

```
#wrapper{
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/utBRH/11/)

Note: I don't find any legit reason to use `display: table;`, as you can achieve the same thing using floats with an ease.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: table-cell;
```

is the problem, why don't use just the *block* type?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `display: table-cell;`